# Get sum() in two columns in Laravel 5.4

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I have this table (`Pickups`):

```
+-----------+------------+-------------+------------+
| worker_id | box_weight | bag_weight |    date    |
+-----------+------------+-------------+------------+
|         1 |          2 |           5 | 11-07-2018 |
|         1 |          7 |           9 | 11-07-2018 |
|         2 |          8 |          11 | 11-07-2018 |
|         2 |          7 |          12 | 11-07-2018 |
+-----------+------------+-------------+------------+
```

and I want in Laravel 5.4 Eloquent database engine get the sum of the box_weight and the bag_weight like this:

```
+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+------------+
| worker_id | sum(box_weight) | sum(bag_weight) |    date    |
+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+------------+
|         1 |               9 |              14 | 11-07-2018 |
|         2 |              15 |              23 | 11-07-2018 |
+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+------------+
```

Until now I could only retrieve the sum of a single column not the both in the same call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the answer bellow, since you didn't mention you want sum of same date per worker id or all dates, I assume only same date, if you want sum of all dates per worker id, remove `date` from `groupBy`

**Eloquent Query**

```
Pickup::select(['worker_id ','date',DB::raw('sum(box_weight)'),DB::raw('sum(bag_weight)')])
    ->groupBy('worker_id','date')
    ->get();
```

**or in Query Builder Approach**

```
DB::table('pickups')
->select(['worker_id ','date',DB::raw('sum(box_weight)'),DB::raw('sum(bag_weight)')])
->groupBy('worker_id','date')
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the MySql query or Laravel's QueryBuilder/Eloquent?

I'm assuming you want it grouped by `worker_id` and not by `date`, if it's by `date`, just add date to the `groupBy`

*In the future, show us what you've tried and you're trying to accomplish in more detail*

If you're looking for the MySqlQuery, Rom's answer will do just fine

```
SELECT worker_id, sum(box_weight), sum(bag_weight), date
FROM pickups
GROUP BY worker_id
```

If you're going from the `Eloquent model`:

```
//Assuming Pickup is your model name
Pickup::selectRaw('worker_id, sum(box_weight), sum(bag_weight), date')
->groupBy('worker_id')->get();
```

Using `DB`

```
DB::table('pickups')->selectRaw('worker_id, sum(box_weight), sum(bag_weight), date')
->groupBy('worker_id')->get();

//Or even

DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT worker_id, sum(box_weight), sum(bag_weight), date
                    FROM pickups
                    GROUP BY worker_id');
```

This will give you a collection of pickups, place `toArray()` at the end of the query if you wish to convert it to an array

The reason behind selectRaw is due to not being able to use `->sum()` with `->select()`. It works just fine for the sum of a column, not for multiple output and the same goes for select, as it can't relate `sum(column)` as a column